# switch content class after click image link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i want build a similar concept of this site https://www.marketingprofsu.com/course/list

with 2 image , when click on a image compare a specific content on bottom of image(fullwidth).this require also is responsive

how make this ?
the markup is similar this:

```
<div class="imagecontainer"></div>

<div class="image1"></div>
<div class="image2"></div>
</div>


<div class="contentcontainer"></div>

<div class="content1"></div>
<div class="content2"></div>
</div>
```

**update**

i have tested evry code posted but nver work in my page not understand why,this is a page :

```
<?php
if ( !defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}
?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <div class="row archive-courses course-list archive_switch" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ItemList">

        <?php
        // Start the Loop.
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
            learn_press_get_template( 'archive-course-content.php' );
        endwhile;
        // Previous/next page navigation.

        ?>
    </div>
    <?php
    learn_press_course_paging_nav();
endif;
?>
```

view a mistake in every test.

Comment: First off, what have you tried so far? Post that code. You have 2 questions here; 1)switch content based on click, 2)make a responsive page. Bear in mind that SO doesn't wtite code for you!

Answer (score 0):

Look at my example.

```js
$('li').click(function(){
  $(this).parent().find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
  $('.content').hide();
  
  
  var content = $(this).attr('ref');
  $('#'+ content).show();
});
```

```css
ul {
  width: 100%;
}
ul li {
  width:100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ccc;
  line-height: 100px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul li:hover,
ul li.selected {
  background-color: #eee;
}



div.content {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li ref="div-1" class="selected">Button 1</li>
    <li ref="div-2">Button 2</li>
<ul>
  
<div>
    <div id="div-1" class="content">Div 1</div>
    <div id="div-2" class="content" style="display: none;">Div 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: hi, thanks for reply, i test and in jy page not work , i posted the code page i want insert this on     <div class="row archive-courses course-list archive_switch" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ItemList">
, but when insert your code not sho anithing,

Comment: it's an example, you can do more with my solution :)

Answer (score 0):

just listen to click on the image and switch content visibility... i ve made a snippet that switch the content with fade effect... you can add more image and content and use the same logic

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    $('.image').on("click",function(){
        if(!$(this).find("img").hasClass("selected")){
            $(".image img").removeClass("selected");
            $(this).find("img").addClass("selected");
            
            $('.content').hide();
            $("."+$(this).attr("rel")).fadeIn();
        }
    });
    
});
```

```css
.image > img{
    padding: 50px;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}

.selected{
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.content{
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 50%;
    display: inline;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="imagecontainer"></div>

<div class="image" rel="content1"><img width="100px" class="img1 selected" src="http://www.cliparthut.com/clip-arts/124/pink-circle-clip-art-124566.png"></img></div>
<div class="image" rel="content2"><img width="100px" class="img2"  src="http://www.cliparthut.com/clip-arts/124/pink-circle-clip-art-124566.png"></img></div>



<div class="contentcontainer">

<div class="content content1">HELLO content 1</div>
<div class="content content2" style="display:none;">HELLO content 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: hi, thanks for reply, i test and in jy page not work , i posted the code page i want insert this on     <div class="row archive-courses course-list archive_switch" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ItemList">
, but when insert your code not sho anithing,

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it:

```
$(".img").click(function(){
    $(".content").hide();
    $("."+$(this).attr("content")).fadeToggle(true);
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3bc4kqxr/1/)

Comment: hi, thanks for reply, i test and in jy page not work , i posted the code page i want insert this on     <div class="row archive-courses course-list archive_switch" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ItemList">
, but when insert your code not sho anithing,

Comment: ok have solved , but if try to make responsive , create proble , i try to make wifth of circle 50% and height auto but create a mistake

Comment: Can you provide a JSFiddle so we can see what is happening?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/soymg3d7/ , i want a responsive with width of 50%, when insert this the height have a problem

Comment: have solved without css background but with img src,  now ha a question how set the firt content already opened when load the page ?,

Comment: In css replace `.content` with `.content:not(:first-child)` like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/3bc4kqxr/4/)